# How do I give the RichTextBox a flat look?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, themes, uxtheme

I'm working on a WinForms SmartClient application, which uses a lot of RichTextBox controls - some in place of the regular TextBox for various reasons. Unfortunately the RichTextBox draws the ugly Win95 3D border instead of the themed XP or Vista style border.

Does anyone know of a way to apply the themed border to the RichTextBox? I don't mind subclassing them for this purpose.

Thanks!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is really a hack but one thing you can do is drop a Panel control onto the page. Give it a BorderStyle of FixedSingle (it will be None by default.)

Drop your RichTextBox into the panel and set the BorderStyle to none. Then set the Dock property of the RichTextBox to Fill.

This will give you a RichTextBox with a flat border.

Comment: I followed this advice, except I used a group box. +1

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day I had to solve this with a panel where the text box is a component inside and had DockPadding set to 3 or 4 pixels. I'd then style that panel to a single pixel.

I always found this really annoying!

Comment: This is really annoying and there has to be a better way as this doesn't give the true textbox theme.

Comment: I sometimes wonder why they didn't make a BorderStyle called 'TextBox'? :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is VB.NET code, it inflates the nonclient area with -1 and then fills the nonclient area with caded blue. It can be converted to C# using SharpDevelop 4.4. I derived the code from this article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13723/Themed-RichTextBox-A-RichTextBox-with-XP-styled-bo

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Class FlatRichTextBox
    Inherits RichTextBox

    Private BorderRect As RECT

    Sub New()
        If VisualStyleInformation.IsEnabledByUser Then
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
        Const WM_NCPAINT = &H85
        Const WM_NCCALCSIZE = &H83
        Const WM_THEMECHANGED = &H31A

        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_NCPAINT
                WmNcpaint(m)
            Case WM_NCCALCSIZE
                WmNccalcsize(m)
            Case WM_THEMECHANGED
                UpdateStyles()
            Case Else
                MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub WmNccalcsize(ByRef m As Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)

        If Not VisualStyleInformation.IsEnabledByUser Then Return

        Dim par As New NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS()
        Dim windowRect As RECT

        If m.WParam <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            par = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS)), NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS)
            windowRect = par.rgrc0
        End If

        Dim clientRect = windowRect

        clientRect.Left += 1
        clientRect.Top += 1
        clientRect.Right -= 1
        clientRect.Bottom -= 1

        BorderRect = New RECT(clientRect.Left - windowRect.Left,
                              clientRect.Top - windowRect.Top,
                              windowRect.Right - clientRect.Right,
                              windowRect.Bottom - clientRect.Bottom)

        If m.WParam = IntPtr.Zero Then
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(clientRect, m.LParam, False)
        Else
            par.rgrc0 = clientRect
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(par, m.LParam, False)
        End If

        Const WVR_HREDRAW = &H100
        Const WVR_VREDRAW = &H200
        Const WVR_REDRAW = (WVR_HREDRAW Or WVR_VREDRAW)

        m.Result = New IntPtr(WVR_REDRAW)
    End Sub

    Private Sub WmNcpaint(ByRef m As Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)

        If Not VisualStyleInformation.IsEnabledByUser Then Return

        Dim r As RECT
        GetWindowRect(Handle, r)

        r.Right -= r.Left
        r.Bottom -= r.Top
        r.Top = 0
        r.Left = 0

        r.Left += BorderRect.Left
        r.Top += BorderRect.Top
        r.Right -= BorderRect.Right
        r.Bottom -= BorderRect.Bottom

        Dim hDC = GetWindowDC(Handle)
        ExcludeClipRect(hDC, r.Left, r.Top, r.Right, r.Bottom)

        Using g = Graphics.FromHdc(hDC)
            g.Clear(Color.CadetBlue)
        End Using

        ReleaseDC(Handle, hDC)
        m.Result = IntPtr.Zero
    End Sub

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function GetWindowRect(hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function GetWindowDC(hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function ReleaseDC(hWnd As IntPtr, hDC As IntPtr) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("gdi32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function ExcludeClipRect(hdc As IntPtr, nLeftRect As Integer, nTopRect As Integer, nRightRect As Integer, nBottomRect As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public Structure NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS
        Public rgrc0, rgrc1, rgrc2 As RECT
        Public lppos As IntPtr
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>
    Public Structure RECT
        Public Left As Integer
        Public Top As Integer
        Public Right As Integer
        Public Bottom As Integer

        Public Sub New(left As Integer, top As Integer, right As Integer, bottom As Integer)
            Me.Left = left
            Me.Top = top
            Me.Right = right
            Me.Bottom = bottom
        End Sub
    End Structure
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a little too late, but nonetheless.

You can always use P/Invoke and subclass your RichEdit with UXTheme API that way you can disable/enable it as you wish.

I think CodeProject had an richedit control which used UXTheme/Visual Styles API

[Visual Styles UXTheme API may become obsolete or deprecated as Windows 8 is rolling out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773178%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Another Hack (VB.NET)] Create a Label and Add Code:

```
Label backcolor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent 
Label.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
myRichTextBox.BringToFront
Label.Width=  myRichTextbox.Width + 4
Label.Height = myRichTextbox.Height + 4 
Label.left = myRichTextBox.left -2
Label.Top = myRichTextboxTop -2
```

Hope it helps
Vincenzo

Answer (score -4):

The easiest way to get rid of the 3D-border is to set another one:

```
richTextBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
```

The `FixedSingle`-BorderStyle is the closest to the `FlatStyle` of e.g. Button