# how to have colored single border line for rich textbox and buttons in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, richtextbox, border

For rich textbox in vb.net i want to have single border line. Fixed single and Fixed 3D are having some dimensional effect which i do not want. And i would also like to change the color of the border.

And same thing with the button, for them how to have single line border and specified color.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I give the RichTextBox a flat look?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700479/how-do-i-give-the-richtextbox-a-flat-look)

Comment: Use a third party Textbox-Control f.e. http://www.textcontrol.com/en_US/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.borderstyle.aspx), the richtextbox doesn't support FixedSingle, so it defaults to Fixed3D.  You could put the RTB into a panel and set the RTBs border to none and the panel's border to fixed single.